# How do I re-render a network graph in react?

Tags: reactjs, rerender, sigma.js

I am developing a visualization application that uses React and react-sigma. One feature is to change the node size depending on what node centrality is selected by the user. My node list updates but my network graph does not. My network graph remains as the initial set of nodes and edges upon loading of the page.

Here is my Parent component:

```
import FilterMenu from "../components/Filter";
import AuthorDetails from "../components/AuthorDetails";
import Network from "../components/Network";

import "../style/Explore.css"

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Explore = () => {

    const [clickedNode, setClickedNode] = useState({});
    const onNodeClick = (e)=> {
      setClickedNode(e.data.node);
    }

    const [centrality,setCentrality]=useState('degree');
    const handleCentralityChange=(e)=>{
        setCentrality(e.target.value)
    }
  
    return (
        <>
            {/* <FilterMenu /> */}
            <div>
                <form>
                    <input type="radio" value="degree" id="degree" onChange={handleCentralityChange} name="centrality" />
                    <label for="degree">Degree Centrality</label>

                    <input type="radio" value="betweenness" id="betweenness" onChange={handleCentralityChange} name="centrality" />
                    <label for="betweenness">Betweenness Centrality</label>

                    <input type="radio" value="closeness" id="closeness" onChange={handleCentralityChange} name="centrality" />
                    <label for="closeness">Closeness Centrality</label>

                    <input type="radio" value="eigenvector" id="eigenvector" onChange={handleCentralityChange} name="centrality" />
                    <label for="eigenvector">Eigenvector Centrality</label>
                </form>
            </div>

            <Network  onClick={ onNodeClick } centrality={ centrality }/>
            <AuthorDetails className="auth-details" data={ clickedNode } />
        </>
    )
}

export default Explore
```

And here is the Network component (data is fetched from Neo4j database)

```
    import { Sigma, RandomizeNodePositions, NOverlap, ForceAtlas2} from 'react-sigma';
import { useReadCypher } from "use-neo4j";

const Network = ({ centrality, onClick }) => {
    var nodes = []
    var edges = []
    var authors = []
    
    const { loading, error, records } = useReadCypher(
                'MATCH (a1:Author)-[r:COAUTHORED_WITH]->(a2:Author) RETURN \
                    \
                    a1.id as a1_id, a1.auth_name as a1_name, a1.auth_affname as a1_aff, \
                    a1.degree_centrality as a1_degree, a1.betweenness_centrality as a1_betweenness, \
                    a1.closeness_centrality as a1_closeness, a1.eigenvector_centrality as a1_eigenvector, \
                    a1.leiden_community as a1_leiden, a1.sbm_community as a1_sbm, \
                    a1.topic_community as a1_topic, a1.auth_papers as a1_count, \
                    \
                    a2.id as a2_id, a2.auth_name as a2_name, a2.auth_affname as a2_aff, \
                    a2.degree_centrality as a2_degree, a2.betweenness_centrality as a2_betweenness, \
                    a2.closeness_centrality as a2_closeness, a2.eigenvector_centrality as a2_eigenvector, \
                    a2.leiden_community as a2_leiden, a2.sbm_community as a2_sbm, \
                    a2.topic_community as a2_topic, a2.auth_papers as a2_count, \
                    \
                    r.id as r_id, r.year as r_year, r.weight as r_weight \
                    \
                    LIMIT 1000 \
                ')
            
    if( loading ) return <h1>Loading...</h1>
    if( error ) return <h1>{ error.message }</h1>

    records?.map((record)=>{
          var source = "";
          var target = "";

          if(!authors.includes(record.get('a1_name'))) {
              source = "n"+nodes.length;
              authors.push(record.get('a1_name'));
              nodes.push({id:source, label: record.get('a1_name'), size: record.get('a1_'+centrality), 
                          affiliation: record.get('a1_aff'), degree: record.get('a1_degree'),
                          betweenness: record.get('a1_betweenness'), closeness: record.get('a1_closeness'),
                          eigenvector: record.get('a1_eigenvector'), leiden: record.get('a1_leiden'),
                          sbm: record.get('a1_sbm'), topic: record.get('a1_topic'), paper_count: record.get('a1_count')
              }); 
          } else{
              source = "n"+(authors.indexOf(record.get('a1_name')) + 1);
          }

          if(!authors.includes(record.get('a2_name'))) {
              target = "n"+nodes.length;
              authors.push(record.get('a2_name'));
              nodes.push({id:target, label: record.get('a2_name'), size:record.get('a2_'+centrality), 
                          affiliation: record.get('a2_aff'), degree: record.get('a2_degree'),
                          betweenness: record.get('a2_betweenness'), closeness: record.get('a2_closeness'),
                          eigenvector: record.get('a2_eigenvector'), leiden: record.get('a2_leiden'),
                          sbm: record.get('a2_sbm'), topic: record.get('a2_topic'), paper_count: record.get('a2_count') 
              }); 
          }   else {
              target = "n"+(authors.indexOf(record.get('a2_name')) + 1);
          }

          edges.push({id:"e"+edges.length, source: source, target: target, year: record.get('r_year')})
    

    });

    console.log(nodes)

    return ( 
      <div className="graph-window">
        <Sigma
          renderer="webgl" 
          graph={{ nodes, edges}}
          settings={{ drawEdges: true, clone: false }} 
          onClickNode={ onClick } >
      <RandomizeNodePositions/> 
      <ForceAtlas2 worker barnesHutOptimize barnesHutTheta={0.6} iterationsPerRender={10} linLogMode timeout={3000}/>
      </Sigma>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Network;
```

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `nodes` as a state and setState (instead of `nodes.push`) for it to trigger re-render Network component:

```
const [nodes, setNodes] = useState([])

...
useEffect(() => {
 let newNodes = []
 records?.map((record, index) => {
    ...
    newNodes = [...newNodes, {
      id: source,
      size:record.get('a2_'+centrality),
      .
      .
      .
    }]
    if(index === records.length - 1) setNodes([...nodes, ...newNodes])
  })

}, [])
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried this but it causes an error that says

Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

because I have a hundred thousand nodes

Comment: so instead of `setNodes` each time you loop in `records.map(...)`, create a variable in useEffect and push each time you loop. Then use `setNodes` only 1 time after all. I'll fix my answer to fit to your case

Comment: Will try this new approach. Thank you!

Comment: I encountered another problem that says newNodes are not iterable. When I try to declare it as another variable, there are no nodes graphed in my webpage

Comment: sorry, just edit the answer again. Init newNodes with an empty array will fix it

Comment: done this ^ but still no graph drawn on my webpage. also the list of nodes do not update onchange of centrality measures

Comment: Just have a little modify on the answer, try it again bro

Comment: sorry i still got the same problem. would fetching data every change in centrality re-render the graph?